# Removing svg text elements with d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I can change the value of the text with a smooth little tween, but every time I am emptying one svg and creating a new one. This eventually loads the DOM up with empty SVGs. How can I get rid of them?

D3:

```
var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
        commasFormatter = '$' + d3.format(",.0f"),
        numVis = d3.select("#defecit"),
        defTotal = d3.select("#defense");


    function init () {
            //Initialize mean text
            numVis.append("text")
                .attr("id", "meantext")
                .attr("y", 40)
                .attr("x", 118)
                .style("font-size", "26px")
                .style("font-family","Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
                .style('font-weight', 'bold')
                .style('text-color', '#525252');

            defTotal.append("text")
                .attr("id", "defense")
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("x", 0)
                .style("font-size", "16px")
                .style("font-family","Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
                .style('font-weight', 'bold')
                .style('text-color', '#525252');

            d3.select("#meantext")
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .ease('linear')
            .tween("text", function() {
                var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, dollars.value);
                return function(t) {
                  this.textContent = '$' + d3.format(",")(Math.round(i(t)));
                };
              })

//Doing something like this didn't work - kept giving me an error that the object array had no exit function
d3.select("meantext").exit().remove()



    }
```

Comment: You want `d3.select("#meantext").remove()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I tried that. It still doesn't pull the empty svg off the DOM.

Comment: Where do you append the SVG?

Comment: To an svg with the id of "defecit". Then I append the svg with a text element with an id of meantext. It every time the init function runs (when soemone presses a button) A new text element appears in the DOM.

Comment: I'm confused now. Do you want to remove the `text` element or the SVG? In any caase, what you need to do is `d3.select("#idOfElement").remove()`.

Comment: Cool, I'll add this as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a specific element, do `d3.select("#idOfElement").remove()`. There's no need for `.exit()` here as no data is being matched and bound.